# Open Specific Page of App from Push Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

When the user gets a push notification I'm trying to open the app to a specific page.

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
myGourpsNotifications *notificationViewController = [[myGourpsNotifications alloc] init];
[navController pushViewController:notificationViewController animated:YES];
```

This is in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` right now just to test it out. I understand it should be in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` but just for testing purposes. When I run this, the app opens to the page I want but all that shows is the navBar and the rest of the screen is black.

Comment: How do you usually access myGourpsNotifications (notificationViewController)? I would say you are not initialising it properly

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

with

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.window.rootViewController];
```

but you have to first initialise rootViewController of app delegate window.

After that you can push any PushViewController to this navController.

Other screen is black just because of that you didn't assign rootViewController of navController and you push another ViewController on it.

Hope this will help you.